# How to work with sql file

Tags: mysql, sql

So I've installed mysql via the web community installer, I've opened up mysql workbench and I've clicked on 'open mysql script' to import a very large .sql file I have.

I don't see any info of any sort though. Just a blank page and I don't see an option to get at any of the data that should be there (10GB file, took a while to open up), what do I have to do to look inside?

Comment: Use **less filename** or **more filename** Command from commandline to take a look into the file. 10GB is to big for workbench

Comment: i am nearly sure that **more** is installed on Windows Systems

Comment: just checked it is, i get what seems to be a list of SET (seem to be features), mind telling me how i could say export a subset of one of these?